# Is there any penalty for being vote kicked?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

I've been playing a lot of Rainbow Six Siege lately, and I was wondering if there is any punishment for being vote kicked too often?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only penalty I can think of, your nick will become recognizable and you will be kicked as soon as someone connects the dots. Otherwise, there is no system implemented which would punish you for being kicked often.